# Regular Language accepted by a Finite State Machine

Tags: regular-language, finite-state-machine

If L is a finite-size language then L is a regular language, meaning that
it can be accepted by a finite state machine. Prove this by defining how
to build—for any finite-size language L—a finite state machine M that
accepts L and prove that L(M) = L. (Hint: a finite-size language has the
notion of the “longest” word and a finite state machine can have a lot of
states as long as its a finite number.)

(A **language** is a set of strings. A language is written using an alphabet. Σ = alphabet and Σ* = all words. L ⊆ Σ* is a language)

I have tried this question and haven't figured out how to define this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start small. Say L has two distinct words $w$ and $w'$. How would you build a finite state machine then? Maybe try it concretely over the alphabet $\{a, b\}$. Also, do your machines have to be deterministic? This question is easier with nondeterminism.

Comment: I believe it doesn't matter if the machine is non-deterministic or deterministic. We can use either. would the finite state machine have two states; one for w and one for w'?

Comment: The finite state machines I'm familiar with start at a starting state without having read anything (possibly multiple starting states for nondeterministic machines), and read one character at a time to transition to new states, rather than reading whole words. Try drawing deterministic machines for the languages $L_1 = \{ab, ba\}$ and $L_2 = \{aab, ab\}$ and see if that helps.

Comment: Ok I will try drawing out diagrams for those languages

Comment: Alright @NicholasViggiano I think Ive got the correct diagrams for those two machines. I'm still confused about how to "Prove this be defining how to build a finite state machine that accepts L and prove that L(M) = L" Do you just explain how the diagram works?? How do I properly answer the question?

Comment: Do you mean the language has a finite number of strings?

Comment: @copper.hat yes, the language has a finite number of strings

Comment: You can post your diagrams so we can check that you have the idea. Once you know how to build a machine for a two-string language, you can inductively show how to build a machine for an $n$-string language. It's the same idea as starting with a 1-string language and turning it into a 2-string language.

Comment: How do I post my pictures? It won't let me in the comments. Do I have to post them in the question itself?

Comment: You can upload them to an image-hosting site and post the link.

Comment: @puj Yes, unfortunately these are incorrect :( First, they are nondeterministic, which is fine, but notice the first one accepts the string $b$, which is not in the language, as well as the string $a$ (as well as $aab$, $aaab$, etc.). [Here is how I would draw deterministic machines](https://i.imgur.com/cEzcEVF.jpg) (I use determinism because I think it is easier for a beginner to think about). Notice that the $L_2$ machine has one more state than necessary, but we're not trying to find the minimal machine, so we should just use the simplest construction.

Comment: @NicholasViggiano Ah ok that makes sense now. Thanks. So now to answer the question am I just supposed to explain how to build the example machines that I've drawn?

Comment: Would you use induction to prove this? That if it holds for the example machine (the base case) then it will hold for any example machine with a finite number of states ?

Comment: No, not every language looks like these languages, these machines aren't universal. First, show how to build a machine for a language containing an *arbitrary single word*. Then, show that for *any* language made up of exactly $n$ words, assuming you know how to build every machine for languages of fewer than $n$ words, you can use one of them to build a new machine for your new language.

Comment: The point of the examples was to give you some intuition about how to build such a machine. If you have a machine accepting only the string ab, how do you turn that into our machine for $L_2$? This is a specific example of the general construction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be a finite language in alphabet $\Sigma$ and let $n\in\Bbb N$ be the length of the longest word in $L$.

First let's build a very "large" machine that accepts the language $L_0=\Sigma^{\,\leq n}$ consisting of **all** the strings in alphabet $\Sigma$ with less than or equal to $n$ symbols. The machine I will build is by no means the simplest machine that recognises $L_0$, but it will serve as a template for building a machine for $L$.

It looks like a big tree, each state has an arrow for each symbol in the alphabet, and each arrow goes to a unique new state until we have read an input of length $n$. After that all states will send every longer input to a reject state. Every state is an accept state, except for the last state.

For example, if $\Sigma = \{0,1,2\}$ and $n=3$ the finite state machine looks like this:

[image]

Any of the accept states corresponds to a single string. For example, the bottom-most state can only be the final state if the input is the empty string, and the state in the top layer, fourth from the left only can be the final state if the input is $010$. Any string of length $4$ or longer will end up in the top most state, and will not be accepted.

Now, to create the machine for $L$, we simply "switch off" all the accept states that correspond to strings that are not in $L$. So if $010\notin L$, the state in the top layer, fourth from the left will become a reject state.

Of course, you can merge a lot of states to get a more compact machine later, but the thing we were interested in was that there *exists* a machine. For that purpose this is good enough.